# SpaceX Lunar Mission when possibly will it take place in future?

Tags: spacex, lunar-landing, spacex-starship

As SpaceX has delayed the crewed *Lunar Mission* which was going to happen in 2018 and now as currently, BFR is in progress, and also as SpaceX has mentioned in the first half of 2019 it will conduct tests on BFR, now I just wanted to know what are the possibilities that when will this *Lunar Mission* happen in the near future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mentioned in this article https://www.marketwatch.com/story/spacex-postpones-plans-to-send-first-space-tourists-around-the-moon-2018-06-03 that they are now targeting around `mid-2019 or longer`

Answer (score 6):

There has been no formal update on this since the Feb 5th, 2018 announcement by [Elon](http://www.spacenews.com/spacex-no-longer-planning-crewed-missions-on-falcon-heavey/) that they would not use Falcon Heavy and use BFR for these launches.